# How do I set a console command to run at start up on Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have about a paragraph worth of console commands that will address some inconveniences I have to go through with using this browser, but they have to run each time at startup.  How can this process by automated?

Comment: What OS? Do they need to run at Firefox startup, or at OS startup? Have you looked at the Firefox shortcut to see how it works? What about writing a script to run your commands and then start Firefox and have your shortcut run that script? What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

- Make a batch file with the commands.
- At the beginning of the file, add the line `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`. (Prepend `start`  if you want Firefox to keep running, but let the CMD prompt called  by the batch file to finish.)
- Make a desktop shortcut and/or a keyboard shortcut to the .bat file.
- If you'd like, set the *Run:* property of the shortcut to *Minimized* to hide the CMD prompt popup.

Comment: That sadly didn't launch firefox and execute any browser console commands.  When I say I want to run console commands on startup, I am referring to running commands through the Browser Console.

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html